# How can I recreate this effect/transition/animation? (HTML/CSS/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transform

I am trying to do some transition/transform effect as you can see on [this site](http://camps.winshape.org/), where the navigation switches halfway the page and kinda transfers into the other one.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on0j9yhh/2/), with two navs, the `.mobilenav` is the one that should be changed upon scrolling, and the `.desktopnav` is the one which slides out as you can see. But now I was wondering how I can make recreate that transition. (The changing nav is done in JQuery with a if, else statement and `($(window).scrollTop() > 500)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simulated that nav pretty close in my fiddle, with some simplifications of course: https://jsfiddle.net/pttsky/0anpeLj0/

There are couple of key concepts:

1. There is actually only one nav to which we add `.full` class to indicate state change.
2. There is a container of `nav`, actual `nav` and its child `li` elements
3. Each of above listed has own CSS transitions and animations that change their positioning, opacity and backgrounds.

Talking deeper on changing nav from collapsed to full-width like on that site.

1. The container block slightly pulling upwards the nav. It becomes non-transparent, which gives an illusion that `border-radius` disappeared from the nav, but actually if we'd animated border-radius, that would be ugly.

   ```
   .nav-container {
     display: block;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 2;
     top: 0;
     padding: 25px 25px 15px;
     -webkit-transition: .8s;
     transition: .8s;
   }
   .full {
     background: #fff;
     padding-top: 15px;
   }
   ```
2. The child elements, except `MENU` link, have `max-width: 0` by default. When menu is hovered, or when it is in full-width state, elements have `max-width: 200px`, and `MENU` has reversed behaviour:

   ```
   .nav-main .item {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     max-width: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: .8s;
     transition: .8s;
     /* limit width */
     overflow: hidden;
     line-height: 3em;
   }

   .nav-main .toggle {
     max-width: 200px;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: .6s .4s;
     transition: .6s .4s;
   }

   .full .nav-main .item {
     max-width: 200px;
     opacity: 1;
   }

   .full .nav-main .item + .item {
     margin-left: 12vw;
   }

   .full .nav-main .toggle {
     max-width: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: .1s;
     transition: .1s;

   }
   ```
3. When changing state, all items of nav seems like fade out then fade in. I've added the appropriate animation to the whole nav:

   ```
   /* nav full-width */
   @keyframes blink {
     0%, 100% {
       opacity: 1;
     }
     50% {
       opacity: 0;
     }
   }

   .full .nav-main {
     animation: blink .8s;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort and help! Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Device's answer, you could also use css transitions on one nav to get the same effect, instead of using two navs.

By switching the class on the nav you can trigger the transition and place the navigation in its correct place.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nav = $('.desktopnav');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrolltop > 500 && !nav.hasClass('scrolled')) {
      nav.addClass('scrolled');
    }
    else if (scrolltop <= 500 && nav.hasClass('scrolled')) {
      nav.removeClass('scrolled');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.desktopnav {
  /* ... snipped, unchanged ... */
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.desktopnav>ul {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.desktopnav>ul>.dropdown {
  /* ... snipped, unchanged ... */
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

/* ... snipped unchanged styles for the unscrolled menu ... */

.desktopnav.scrolled {
  top: 0px;
  right: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.desktopnav.scrolled>ul {
  margin-top:0px;
  background: #fff;
}

.desktopnav.scrolled>ul>.dropdown {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.desktopnav.scrolled>ul>.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  max-width: 1000px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 19px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q80k0y7v/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort and help! Appreciated!